# Unable to install cocoapods on Catalina

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, macos-catalina, xcode12

I have catalina OS 10.15.7 and XCode Version 12.4 (12D4e)
I am trying to install cocoapods using gem:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

It has been a nightmare to resolve this.
I tried using brew install. Brew is able to install it. But the pod does not work. when I use simple commands like

```
pod init
or 
pod -v
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1399:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/pankajnafria/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec' , execute `gem env` for more information
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1401:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/pankajnafria/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/specifications/activesupport-6.1.4.1.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information
```

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3623

Answer (score 8):

Open Terminal

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then, **close and reopen** terminal

```
rvm install ruby-3.1.1
```

When finished, run:

```
rvm use ruby-3.1.1
```

And then:

```
rvm --default use 3.1.1
```

Next step, install cocoapods using:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

For more info, check this [link].(https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697249)

Comment: I got this error: 

Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml libksba readline zlib openssl@1.1',
please read /Users/mike_jones/.rvm/log/1668644971_ruby-3.1.1/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_coreutils_libyaml_libksba_readline_zlib_openssl@1.1.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by reinstalling Ruby/Rubygems and CocoaPods.

First, I followed Moncef Belyamani's thorough [instructions for installing Ruby/Rubygems](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/?utm_source=stackoverflow).

Next, I ran several commands:

```
gem install json
gem install CFPropertyList
gem pristine json --version 2.6.1
```

Per suggestion from [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11134#issuecomment-1006720011):

```
gem update --system 3.2.33
```

And I reinstalled CocoaPods:

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
brew cleanup -s
brew install cocoapods
```